# Apply continuous filter to map dots in Qlik

Tags: geospatial, qliksense

I am trying to filter the data points displayed on a map using a slider in Qlik. The goal would be to display only the datapoints with a column value above the slider.

For example, imagine a city/population dataset. The goal would be to display only the cities with a population above a threshold.
How would you implement a slider (Variable input) that would define a value (ex 1 million) and then use it to show only the cities with a population above 1 million?

So far, I tried to use a custom variable, link it to a slider and use it in the data and the display condition of the layer.
What I got was a static map, not reacting to the slider movement.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new variable in the frontend called something like `vPop`:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense variable dialog box]

2. Create a new Variable Input object and choose your new variable. Make it a slider and then set the Min/Max and Step values that you want:

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense Variable Input object properties]

As you can see in the above screenshot, I used the `Min()` and `Max()` functions with the `all` keyword, which will get the min/max regardless of any selections the user makes. I also use the `Floor()` and `Ceil()` functions to get the values to be rounded down and up, respectively, to the nearest 1000.

3. Create a map object and a new point layer. For the dimension, set it up like this:

`=Aggr(Only({<Population={">=$(vPop)"}>} City), City)`

When we use the `Aggr()` function, we are allowed to use a measure with Set Analysis to filter our dimension values. In this case, we use set analysis to filter the `[Population]` field to be greater than or equal to the value of our `vPop` variable.

[image: Qlik Sense map slider screengrab gif]